# Read Gcloud logs programmatically

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to understand what is the equivalent REST api for the cli command:

```
gcloud logging read ....
```

I need to execute a query on logs programmatically from a client library (Ruby if possible).
I cannot find nothing in the rest api docs.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Google's documentation for using client libraries with its services, is mostly very good.

Here's the documentation for Ruby for Cloud Logging.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-ruby

I encourage you to use Google's excellent [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) when developing using the client libraries too. APIs Explorer helps you craft REST requests and see the responses and this is very helpful when writing code and debugging:

Here's the APIs Explorer page for the Logging service's method to list log entries:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list

Another very helpful facility is that you can append `--log-http` to **any** `gcloud` command it will show you the underlying REST calls that are being made. This is also helpful in determining how the `gcloud` commands work so that you may write your own code that replicates|extends the functionality:

```sh
gcloud logging read ${FILTER} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--log-http
```

And, finally, the Console's Log Explorer is an excellent way to prototype the filters you'll probably need to use in your client code:

https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query

Hint: when constructing filters, don't forget to escape `"` characters, for example `FILTER="resource.type=\"gce_instance\""`. In this case, the value `gce_instance` must be quoted (`"`) in the filter's value.